# forms.ValidationError aren't being displayed on form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-rest-framework, django-forms

i'm trying to show an error message bellow the input on my register form, although it isn't being showed. On my tests the form is considered invalid by django on the `if respostas_form.is_valid():` condition, but the message that was suposed to be displayed is not apearing.
( the name of variables and funcs of the codes are in portuguese cz i'm brazilian )

**html:**

```
{% for field in cadastro.visible_fields %}
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label class="forms__label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}" class="inputText">{{field.label}}</label>
      {{field}}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{error}}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class CadastroForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.EmailField(
    max_length=100,
    required=True,
    label='Email',
    widget=forms.TextInput({
      "class": 'forms__input',
      "placeholder": "exemplo@gmail.com",
    })
  )
  nome_de_usuario = forms.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    required=True,
    label="Nome de usuário",
    widget=forms.TextInput({
      "class": 'forms__input',
      "placeholder": "Ex.: Jóse Dávila",
    })
  )
  senha = forms.CharField(
    max_length=70,
    required=True,
    label="Senha",
    widget=forms.PasswordInput({
      "id": "userPasswordInput",
      "class": 'forms__input',
      "placeholder": "Exemplo1234+",
    })
  )
  senha2 = forms.CharField(
    max_length=70,
    required=True,
    label="Confirme sua senha",
    widget=forms.PasswordInput({
      "id": "userPasswordInput",
      "class": 'forms__input',
      "placeholder": "Exemplo1234+",
    })
  )


  def clean_senha2(self):
    senha = self.cleaned_data.get('senha')
    senha2 = self.cleaned_data.get('senha2')

    if senha and senha2:
        if senha != senha2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Senhas não são iguais')
        else:
            return senha2
```

**views.py**

```
def cadastrar(request):

  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('inicio')

  cadastro_form = forms.CadastroForm()

  if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
    respostas_form = forms.CadastroForm(request.POST)
    cadastro_result = cadastrar_usuario(request, respostas_form)
    if cadastro_result: return cadastro_result

  return render(request, 'usuarios/cadastrar.html', {
    "cadastro": cadastro_form,
  })
```

**function cadastrar_usuario**

```
def cadastrar_usuario(request, respostas_form:CadastroForm):
  if respostas_form.is_valid():

    nome = respostas_form['nome_de_usuario'].value()
    email = respostas_form['email'].value()
    # nascimento = respostas_form['nascimento'].value()
    senha = respostas_form['senha'].value()

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      messages.error(request, " Já existe um usuário cadastrado com esse email!!")
      return redirect('cadastrar')

    if User.objects.filter(username=nome).exists():
      messages.error(request, " Já existe um usuário cadastrado com esse nome!!")
      return redirect('cadastrar')

    usuario = User.objects.create_user(password=senha, username=nome, email=email)
    usuario.save()

    messages.success(request, f"Olá {nome}, seu cadastro foi efetuado com sucesso!")
    return redirect('entrar')
```

I tryed to show a error message for the `senha2` input field using the djangoss clean method, but it doesn't work

Comment: In `clean_senha2()`, if the condition `if senha and senha2` is not true, the function will not raise a validation error.  It will return `None`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, cz when i was testing i was always difining it, so i just don't worry about it because i was trying to show the message error by getting the both passwords diferent. Although I should return something else than None?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside your view. Currently you are not rendering the `ValidationError` raised in `forms` because you have two different instances `cadastro_form` and `respostas_form`.

The `ValidationError` is inside the latter. And, if your function result is `False` then `cadastro_form` is rendered again. You just need to render the correct `form`.

[`views.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#the-view)

```py
def cadastrar(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('inicio')

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
        cadastro_form = forms.CadastroForm(request.POST)
        cadastrar_usuario(request, cadastro_form)

    else:
        cadastro_form = forms.CadastroForm()

    return render(request, 'usuarios/cadastrar.html', {
        "cadastro": cadastro_form,
    })
```

Comment: oh gosh man, thx, it worked vey well, i was stunk on that bug since yeasterday, really thanks